# PHP Control Structure :Declare()

Tags: php, control-structure

I'm having a hard time understanding  the PHP control structure declare() and where/how it would be used.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php

I was hoping someone could explain this to me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/21/0

> SUMMARY:
>
> Put simply, a tick is a special event
>   that occurs internally in PHP each
>   time it has executed a certain number
>   of statements. These statements are
>   internal to PHP and loosely correspond
>   to the statements in your script. You
>   can control how many statements it
>   takes to set off a tick using the
>   declare() function, and you can
>   register functions to execute when a
>   tick occurs by using the
>   register_tick_function() function.

Comment: That was a great article. Thanks!

Comment: Updated URL: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/21/0/the-declare-function-and-ticks